# Fan humming sound when decreasing speed with a dimmer

Tags: resistors, motor, dimmer, single-phase, rpm

I am using a ~large 400mm wall mounted metalic fan (specs below).

I wanted to decrease the speed (and noise) with light dimmers (I tried 2 models so far) but when speed is decreased it makes humming noises like the speed would fluctuate in waves, like it would be out of balance. One dimmer says 30-400W.

Someone suggested I need a power line noise filter, does that help ? If so, any details on that ?

Others said they are able to decrease fan speed with some ... "power resistors" (I think), I can go this way if the speed/noise is stable and if I can make it have 2 speeds, what resistors would I need ?

Fan has 2 wires, not 3 or more like a pwm controlled one.

### Fan specs

- single phase
- 230V  / 50 Hz
- power: 180W
- current: 0.82A
- rpm: 1380
- 3400 m³/h

[image]

### Dimmer type used

[image]

Comment: [Fan speed controllers](https://www.amazon.com/Fan-Speed-Control/s?k=Fan+Speed+Control) are [not compatible](https://www.startribune.com/dimmer-switch-ceiling-fan-problem/160111575/) with light dimmers.

Comment: you can use a variac to control the speed by lowering the amplitude instead of chopping the wave.

Comment: I’m voting to move this question because this is better answered at DIY.SE. It clearly is about selecting the proper products for electrical installation. This is not a engineering task.

Answer (score 3):

The fan is not a compatible load for a light dimmer, and the light dimmer is not a compatible power source for the fan.

Light dimmers are for lights, not for fans.

If it reads on the fan that it expects to be directly connected to 230VAC / 50 Hz mains then that is how it must be connected and the speed can't be controlled.

Fans with speed control would have multiple wires from the fan connected to a speed controller which takes in single phase mains.

Comment: What if another dimmer appears to be made for fans (has a fan icon on it), that should work better with the same fan ? As far as I know they work on same 2-wire method. Just not sure what to expect if I try one of those https://www.netvolt.ro/continut/produse/70073/500/zena-alb-mecanism-variator-ventilator-220v200w-st-70073-1-1441622774-35882.jpg

Comment: You need to give a link to a product to see some specs what it is meant for, not to a picture of a product.

Comment: This one for example ? Do you think this is made different than the light dimmers ? (in terms of running smoother). Thanks https://eklimag.ro/variator-electronic-de-turatie-vst-2.html

Comment: The above also has this document, does this mean it is meant for a motor with more wires ? https://eklimag.ro/index.php?dispatch=attachments.getfile&attachment_id=1021

Comment: Sorry I don't understand Romanian manuals. I guess you can, and there are also neat diagrams how connect the fan dimmers with only two wires. If you are unsure about making those connections or need more help, hire an electrician. Also know your local electrical laws and codes. For example changing a light switch yourself to a dimmer in some countries would be illegal due to electrical safety requirements, only a certified electrician is allowed to change them.

Answer (score 1):

Inexpensive speed controlles that are intended for use with single-phase AC fan motors produce variable output voltage by cutting off part of every cycle of the AC voltage sine wave. There are light dimmers that work the same way and may work about as well for fan speed control. Cutting the waveform is going to produce some unavoidable sound. "Line noise filters" are unlikely to help much. Those products may work better with ceiling fans. There could be several reasons that your fan is not really suitable for speed control. There is probably no way to predict what speed control, if any, will provide acceptable performance with your fan.